# Add PHP code to a node

Tags: 7

Is it possible to add PHP code to a node? I have enabled the Context and Context PHP modules.

May anyone please tell me how I can do?

Comment: Do you wish to just add the code to the content or also wish to execute it?

Comment: I want to execute the PHP code in drupal page. I have resolved it. I have forgotten to add role to PHP Code in Text Format. Now i have the option to add PHP code when creating a drupal content

Comment: use input format "PHP"

Answer (score 3):

Enable [PHP Filter](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/php) module comes with Drupal core

> The PHP filter core module adds the ability to include PHP code in
>   posts. PHP is a general-purpose scripting language widely-used for web
>   development; the content management system used by this website has
>   been developed using PHP.

The following is a guide to add a new text format filter in Drupal 7:

1. Navigate to the Text formats page *Administer » Configuration » Content authoring » Text formats* (/admin/config/content/formats).
2. Click **Add Text Format** (admin/config/content/formats/add).
3. Enter the following information:

   - **Name**: The name of the filter as it will appear in the administration interface.
   - **Roles**: Select one or more roles that will be able to use the format.
   - **Enabled filters**: Enable one or more filters.  ***Note**: As filters are selected, items are added to the Filter Processing Order and Filter Settings sections.*
   - In the **Filter processing order** section, drag the four-headed arrow to rearrange the order in which the filters will be applied.
   - In the **Filter settings** section, specify the settings for the selected filters. Some filters do not have settings.
4. Click **Save Changes**

**WARNING**: Some HTML markup should only be available to authenticated and trusted users. **The PHP option should not be enabled unless it is necessary and care should be taken to limit access to a role representing trusted and knowledgeable users.**

Comment: For this, it is required to enable [PHP Filter][1] and go to Admin -> Configuration -> Text Format (admin/config/content/formats) and add role to PHP Code. After this, PHP code format also will be available along with Filtered HTML,Full HTML,Plain Text when creating new content.


  [1]: http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/php